# Fantasy book series with a female shapeshifter lead who is taken to another realm by the creator of werewolves

Tags: story-identification, books, shape-shifter

I can't remember the name of this fantasy book. The female lead is a shapeshifter and has a bad mate. Then the creator of werewolves shows up and takes her away. He can also control shadows. He is a king there. There is a huge library in the realm he takes her to. He also has a fae friend. They also travel across different realms in later books. She is revealed to be the reincarnation of a goddess of creation. And he's her son from the previous life. But okay....

It's a series and all side characters have their stories too.
That's all I can remember. Please help me find this...

Comment: In roughly which year/s did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/64401958

Comment: Wow. This question is just a great big grab bag of fantasy novel tropes, ain't it? :-)